# Force linking of explicitly instantiated static library

Tags: c++, templates, static-libraries, explicit-instantiation

I have some templated header-only class A.hpp:

```
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP
template <int N>
class A
{
A(){}
};

#endif
```

And an explicit instantiation in a corresponding A.cpp:

```
#include "A.hpp"
template class A<2>;
```

I compile the library to an object, and convert it to static library-format:

```
g++ -c A.cpp -I ./
ar rvs libA.a A.o
```

Edit: By adding a constructor, I was able to get symbols out of the object file:

```
nm A.a

A.o:
0000000000000000 W _ZN1AILi2EEC1Ev
0000000000000000 W _ZN1AILi2EEC2Ev
0000000000000000 n _ZN1AILi2EEC5Ev
```

When I afterwards compile a main.cpp:

```
#include "A.hpp"

int main()
{
    A<2> foo();
}
```

```
g++ main.cpp A.a -I ./
```

I still have to include header file A.hpp, so how to I determine if the static library is being used?

Answer (score 0):

By first compiling this to library libA.a:

```
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP
// #include <iostream>
template <int N>
class A
{
    A()
    {
        // std::cout << "Not in use!" << std::endl;
    }
};
template class A<2>;
#endif
```

And afterwards enabling cout in the header:

```
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP
#include <iostream>
template <int N>
class A
{
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "Not in use!" << std::endl;
    }
};
template class A<2>;
#endif
```

It was possible to compile main.cpp and link libA.a:

```
g++ main.cpp -I include/ -L -lA
```

Executing ./a.out resulted in no output, which shows that the static library was used (even though the function body in the header changed).